# How do I clear clustered pushpins from a Bing Map in web API?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

```js
var map, clusterLayer;
function GetMap() {
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap',{
    credentials: 'My Key Here',
    zoom: 3
  });
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {
    //Generate 3000 random pushpins in the map view. 
    var pins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(3000, map.getBounds());
    //Create a ClusterLayer with options and add it to the map.
    clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pins, {
      clusteredPinCallback: createCustomClusteredPin,
      gridSize: 80
    });
    map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
  });

}

function removeEverything() { 
     // None of the following functions seem to work
    //map.entities.clear() ;
    //map.layers.clear() ; 
     map.layers.remove(clusterLayer) ;  
}

function createCustomClusteredPin(){
  // Some Decoration  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script type='text/javascript'

            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have a clustered layer of pushpins on a Bing Map which I generated using the JavaScript API. I created a clustered layer of pushpins and added it to the map. The problem is that I am unable to remove the pushpins from the map once I have added it. I tried many functions from the API but nothing seems to work. The above is my code. Ideally I would also want a feature to hide the *clusterLayer* from the map and present it on a button click. For this I used the *clusterLayer.setOptions({visible:false})* but that is not working too. What am I missing ? Any help is much appreciated.

PS : I am calling the *removeEverything()* function from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionality to clear a clustering layer was added last week to the experimental branch. Add "&branch=experimental" to the map script URL. Then you can clear the cluster layer by doing this:

```
clusterLayer.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you! Also is there a way to hide the clusterLayer from the map so that I can add it again when needed? The clusterLayer.setOptions({visible : false}) doesn't seem to have any effect .

Comment: Hmmm.. this was working in experimental but seems to have regressed. Will have the team look into this.

Comment: Ok I see this answer as I had the same problem with a layer of polygons and used the layer.clear() as shown but it doesn't work.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: Is this still only in the experimental branch?

Comment: This is in the main release branch as well. Generally anything that is in the experimental branch is added to the main release branch in the following month.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a

```js
map.layers.clear();
```

granted - I only have one cluster layer showing.
I'm going to assume this will remove x number of layers  -  in which case - you will eventually have to do it by index.

Comment: This would remove the cluster layer as well from the not. I believe the users wants to only clear the data in the cluster layer, not remove the cluster layer itself.